C performance is worse than node.js in software shader for the linux framebuffer, what is happening? How to improve it?
I would expect for C to be way faster than node.js, but in my application it does not.
I am trying to do a simple software shader animation that changes the linux framebuffer:
In C (out of desperation) I have everything in the main:
// anime.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BYTE 8
#define MAX_BYTE 255

int main()
{
    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
    int fb_fd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if (fb_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error: cannot open framebuffer device");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ioctl(fb_fd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &vinfo) == -1)
    {
        perror("Error reading variable information");
        exit(2);
    }
    int w = vinfo.xres;
    int h = vinfo.yres;
    int color_channels = (vinfo.bits_per_pixel / BYTE);
    long screen_size = w * h * color_channels;
    uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)mmap(0, screen_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb_fd, 0);

    double t = 0;
    while (t < 10)
    {
        long k;
        for (k = 0; k < screen_size; k += color_channels)
        {
            uint32_t i = k / (color_channels * w);
            uint32_t j = (k / color_channels) % w;
            uint32_t x = j;
            uint32_t y = h - 1 - i;
            double px = (double)x * t / w;
            double py = (double)y * t / h;
            uint8_t r = (uint8_t)(MAX_BYTE * px) % MAX_BYTE;
            uint8_t g = (uint8_t)(MAX_BYTE * py) % MAX_BYTE;
            uint8_t b = (uint8_t)0;
            buffer[k] = b;
            buffer[k + 1] = g;
            buffer[k + 2] = r;
            buffer[k + 3] = MAX_BYTE;
        }
        t = t + 0.05;
    }
    munmap(buffer, screen_size);
    close(fb_fd);
    return 0;
}


I compile with gcc anime.c -o anime -lm. And run it sudo ./anime
In node.js:
// anime.mjs
import fs from 'node:fs';

const MAX_BYTE = 255;
const framebufferPath = '/dev/fb0';

const Screen = () => {
    const ans = {};
    ans.width = 2560;
    ans.height = 1440;
    ans.bytesPerPixel = 4;
    ans.channels = 4;
    ans.size = ans.width * ans.height * ans.bytesPerPixel;
    ans.buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(ans.size);
    ans.fb = fs.openSync(framebufferPath, 'r+');
    ans.map = (lambda, time) => {
        const channels = ans.bytesPerPixel;
        const w = ans.width;
        const h = ans.height;
        for (let k = 0; k < ans.size; k += channels) {
            const i = k / (channels * w);
            const j = (k / channels) % w;
            const x = j;
            const y = h - 1 - i;
            const color = lambda(x, y, time);
            if (!color) continue;
            ans.buffer[k] = MAX_BYTE * color[2];
            ans.buffer[k + 1] = MAX_BYTE * color[1];
            ans.buffer[k + 2] = MAX_BYTE * color[0];
            ans.buffer[k + 3] = MAX_BYTE;
        }
        return ans.paint();
    }
    ans.paint = () => {
        fs.writeSync(ans.fb, ans.buffer, 0, ans.size, 0);
        return ans;
    }
    return ans;
}

const screen = Screen();
const render = (x, y, t) => {
    const px = (x * t) / screen.width;
    const py = (y * t) / screen.height;
    return [px % 1, py % 1, 0];
}

const play = ({ oldTime, time }) => {
    const newTime = new Date().getTime();
    const dt = (newTime - oldTime) * 1e-3;
    screen.map(render, time);
    if(time > 10) return;
    setTimeout(() => play({ oldTime: newTime, time: time + dt }));
}
play({ oldTime: new Date().getTime(), time: 0 });

I run it using sudo node anime.mjs.
The performance in C is worse than in node, what am I missing?
By performance, I mean frames per second.

When you benchmark code, always do it with optimizations enabled.

With O2 optimization, I got marginal improvements. Thank you, but still not enough.

What is “the performance”? Also note that your C version always sleeps and your Node version never does, and they seem to measure time differently (50 microsecond sleep, time goes up by 0.05, whereas t seems to be in seconds in the Node version).

Measure measure measure. Find where things are slow

By performance I mean frames per second, thanks for pointing that out.
Also, gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
node version: v22.3.0

To be more explicit: How are you measuring frames per second and what were the specific measured values for each program?

Honestly, just by visual assessment, one is slower than the other. One animation is smooth and the other is not.

That’s not an objective measurement

One tiny thing: you have long screen_size as a limit for iterating with int k.

Why do you have a usleep inside the loop? It seems strange when you are talking performance? Have you measured the runtime of the loop-body without a sleep?

Re usleep: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853240/4386427 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53744280/4386427

You can remove usleep, but it just improves marginally.

BTW: Did you compile with -O2

Yes, still not the bottleneck, but thanks.

What happens if you change fmod(px, 1.0) to (px - (int)px) and the same for py

Already removed fmod and usleep

You seem to be doing two different calculations in C and Node, so the performances might differ for that reason alone; and, depending on platform and compiler options, fmod in double precision might be a costly operation. To check this in depth, I expect valgrind to be your friend.
Full optimization of this part would require something like a Bresenham decomposition and working using uint32 or uint64, but some loop reengineering might work:
        double px = (double)x * t / w;
        double py = (double)y * t / h;
        uint8_t r = (uint8_t)(MAX_BYTE * fmod(px, 1.0));
        uint8_t g = (uint8_t)(MAX_BYTE * fmod(py, 1.0));
        uint8_t b = (uint8_t)0;
        buffer[k] = b;
        buffer[k + 1] = g;
        buffer[k + 2] = r;
        buffer[k + 3] = MAX_BYTE;

could become something like, (I haven't checked, just applied some off-the-cuff changes; there might be an off-by-one error in the calculation of g):
    // Precalculate variables that do not change during frame
    double tw2 = (t/w)*MAX_BYTE;
    double th2 = (t/h)*MAX_BYTE;
    uint8_t *buff = buffer;
    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < h; y++) {
         // g only depends on y
         uint8_t g = ((double)(h-y) * th2) % MAX_BYTE;
         for (uint32_t x = 0; x < w; x++) {
             *(buff++) = 0;
             *(buff++) = g;
             *(buff++) = ((double)x * tw2) % MAX_BYTE;
             *(buff++) = MAX_BYTE;
         }
    }
    t = t + 0.05;
    // What happens if you change the usleep?


I removed the fmod and usleep, still just got a marginal gain, node.js animation is much smoother still. But thanks for the explanation and improvements

In addition to enabling optimizations as mentioned in the comments, the other main problem is that you also need to call msync if you’re using mmap, or there’s no guarantee about when the writes will actually affect the framebuffer.
// anime.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_BYTE 255

int main(void) {
    int fb_fd = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
    if (fb_fd == -1) {
        perror("opening framebuffer device failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int w = 2560;
    int h = 1440;
    int color_channels = 4;
    long screen_size = (long)w * h * color_channels;
    uint8_t* buffer = mmap(0, screen_size, PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb_fd, 0);

    struct timespec last;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &last) != 0) {
        perror("clock_gettime failed");
        return 1;
    }

    double t = 0;
    while (t < 10) {
        for (int k = 0; k < screen_size; k += color_channels) {
            uint32_t i = k / (color_channels * w);
            uint32_t j = (k / color_channels) % w;
            uint32_t x = j;
            uint32_t y = h - 1 - i;
            double px = (double)x * t / w;
            double py = (double)y * t / h;
            uint8_t r = (uint8_t)(MAX_BYTE * fmod(px, 1.0));
            uint8_t g = (uint8_t)(MAX_BYTE * fmod(py, 1.0));
            uint8_t b = (uint8_t)0;
            buffer[k] = b;
            buffer[k + 1] = g;
            buffer[k + 2] = r;
            buffer[k + 3] = MAX_BYTE;
        }

        if (msync(buffer, screen_size, MS_SYNC) != 0) {
            perror("msync failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        struct timespec next;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &next) != 0) {
            perror("clock_gettime failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        t += next.tv_sec - last.tv_sec + (next.tv_nsec - last.tv_nsec) / 1e9;
        last = next;
    }
}

As general advice: start by changing just one thing. If you wanted to compare the performance of a C program with a Node one, you should have had them perform the same operations at first, i.e. use write in C as well, hard-code the same resolution values, perform the same time calculations.
